# Работа с длинными числами(непонятное поведение при выводе второго массива символов)

Tags: c++

Необходимо составить программу,которая будет работать с длинными числами.
Кратко опишу: записываем в программу цифры(в виде строки), после переносим их в конец массива для удобства выполнения мат. операций, потом вывожу введённые числа для проверки правильности.
Проблема заключается в том,что 2-й массив выводит неправильно: иногда может вывести все нолики, а иногда вначале ноли,а потом 1234567... Фишка в том,что если в подпрограмме Vivod в цикле поменять i=0(то есть,чтоб выводило все 300 элементов),то сами элементы,как и должно быть находятся в конце массива и выводится так: 00000000000.... и цифры которые я ввёл. В чем проблема?

ps как можно с помощью atoi приводить к виду int только заданный элемент в массиве(например str[299]). Надо для того,чтобы с конца соответствующие элементы складывать,то есть str[299]+str[299].
    Надо для того,чтобы с конца соответствующие элементы складывать,то есть str[299]+str[299]. 
http://pastie.org/3828708

Comment: Копируйте сюда свой код, выделяете его и давите на кнопку 1001010.

Comment: А чем не нравится gmp?

Comment: А зачем хранить символы, если можно хранить сразу цифры (а если постараться, то и по две цифры на байт.
Преобразовывать символ (сhar c) в цифру(byte d) очень просто - d = с - '0', назад с цифры в символ - c = d + '0'. С таким подходом и математика сильно упростится.

Answer (score 1):

[ВОТ!](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/) Все что вам нужно знать об "atoi" вы можете прочитать отсюда.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int n;
   char a[256];

   cin >> a;

   n = atoi(a);
   cout << n;
   system("PAUSE");
   return 0;
}
```

Вот и наглядный пример. А дальше уже, надо вам самим чуть подумать.

Comment: А если в строке нет цифр, а набрана бессмысленная последовательность символов, применяя atoi, получаете 0. И способа защитить ввод "от дурака" нет. Лучше используйте функции семейства strtol() - во-первых, и ошибки сможете обнаруживать, во-вторых, основание системы счисления, в которой представлено число, задавать.

Comment: ну это я поверхностно написал, т.к и написал, чтоб думать дальше самому. А во-вторых, он сам спросил про "atoi", ну и я про это и написал.